# R programming ggvis histogram verses hist - How to size the buckets, and define X axis spacing (ticks)

Tags: r, histogram, ggvis

I am learning to use ggvis and wanted to understand how to create the equivalent histogram to that produced by hist. Specifically, how do you set the bin widths and upper and lower bounds of x in ggvis histograms? What am I missing?

**Question:** *How do I get the ggvis histogram output to match the hist output?*

Let me provide an example:

```
require(psych)
require(RCurl)
require(ggvis)

if ( !exists("impact") ) {
  url <- "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8272421/stat/stat_one.txt"
  myCsv <- getURL(url, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
  impact <- read.csv(textConnection(myCsv), sep = "\t")
  impact$subject <- factor(impact$subject)
}

describe(impact)

hist(impact$verbal_memory_baseline, 
     main = "Distribution of verbal memory baseline scores", 
     xlab = "score", ylab = "frequency")
```

[image: Example Output of Hist]

Ok, lets try and reproduce with ggvis... the output does not match...

```
impact %>%
ggvis( x = ~verbal_memory_baseline, fill := "white") %>%
layer_histograms(width = 5) %>%
add_axis("x", title = "score") %>%
add_axis("y", title = "frequency")
```

[image: ggvis histogram output]

***How do I get the ggvis output to match the hist output?***

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.2 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] psych_1.5.6      knitr_1.11       ggvis_0.4.2.9000 setwidth_1.0-4  colorout_1.1-1   vimcom_1.2-3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.0          digest_0.6.8         dplyr_0.4.3.9000     assertthat_0.1       mime_0.3            
[6] R6_2.1.1             jsonlite_0.9.16      xtable_1.7-4         DBI_0.3.1            magrittr_1.5        
[11] lazyeval_0.1.10.9000 rstudioapi_0.3.1     rmarkdown_0.7        tools_3.2.2          shiny_0.12.2        
[16] httpuv_1.3.3         yaml_2.1.13          parallel_3.2.2       rsconnect_0.4.1.4    mnormt_1.5-3        
[21] htmltools_0.2.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
impact %>%
  ggvis( x = ~verbal_memory_baseline, fill := "white") %>%
  layer_histograms(width = 5, boundary = 5) %>% 
  add_axis("y", title = "frequency") %>%
  add_axis("x", title = "score", ticks = 5)
```

Which gives:

[image]

---

The official documentation is a bit cryptic about how `boundary` and `center` works. Have a look at DataCamp's [How to Make a Histogram with ggvis in R](http://blog.datacamp.com/make-histogram-ggvis-r/)

> The `width` argument already set the bin width to 5, but where do bins
>   start and where do they end? You can use the `center` or `boundary`
>   argument for this. `center` should refer to one of the bins’ center
>   value, which automatically determines the other bins location. The
>   `boundary` argument specifies the boundary value of one of the bins.
>   Here again, specifying a single value fixes the location of all bins.
>   As these two arguments specify the same thing in a different way, you
>   should set at most one of `center` or `boundary`.

---

If you want the same result using `center` instead of `boundary` try:

```
impact %>%
  ggvis( x = ~verbal_memory_baseline, fill := "white") %>%
  layer_histograms(width = 5, center = 77.5) %>% 
  add_axis("y", title = "frequency") %>%
  add_axis("x", title = "score", ticks = 5)
```

Here you specify the center of a bin (77.5) and it determines all the others automatically

Comment: Steven,

Thank you for answering my question so promptly. I am reading up on the boundary and ticks ggvis information.

Comment: @PeteJarvis Glad it helped ! :)

Comment: Also try `center`  in `layer_histogram`. I think you want to set it to .5.

Comment: @PeteJarvis I added more explanation on the `center` /  `boundary` mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

Stevens answer is correct.

Having his pointers allowed me to read the documentation much more deeply:

**layer_histograms():**

http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggvis/functions/layer_histograms

**Boundary**

- A boundary between two bins. As with center, things are shifted when
  boundary is outside the range of the data. For example, to center on
  integers, use width = 1 and boundary = 0.5, even if 1 is outside the
  range of the data. At most one of center and boundary may be
  specified.

**add_axis()**

http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggvis/functions/add_axis

**ticks**

- A desired number of ticks. The resulting number may be different so
  that values are "nice" (multiples of 2, 5, 10) and lie within the
  underlying scale's range.